# Display appropriate device name with JQuery

Tags: jquery

I'd like to display the users device name by detecting their useragent with Jquery and saving it as a variable.

```
if( userAgent.match( /iPad/i ) || userAgent.match( /iPhone/i ) || userAgent.match( /iPod/i ) ) {
        link = $app_banner.attr('data-ios');
        device = 'iPhone'; }
```

And then retrieve it on the page. So your device is 'iphone'.

How do I do this?

Thanks

Comment: You are answering your own question. navigator.userAgent.match( /iPhone/i ).

Comment: How do I retrieve it to echo it on the page?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this javascript to pop-up it!

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 alert(navigator.userAgent);
});
```